# How to handle variable inside javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, onkeyup

I am trying to amateurishly create an autocomplete input field with jquery. My first step is to get some results displayed below the input field by calling a php script on keyup with the load function of jquery.

I dont know how silly this attempt is, but i think i am almost there. However, I am stuck during passing the keyup variable to the script. Actually I can passa a variable but i need to use the keyup variable to pass.

For clarity on the question please see the code;

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function getres(){
    var x = document.getElementById("cit");
    $('#resdiv').load('results.php?cit=x.value');
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
 <input type="" name="" id="cit" onkeyup="getres()">
<div id='resdiv'></div>
```

PHP file being called results.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['cit'])){echo $_GET['cit']."<br>";}
include('connnew.php');
$getprops=$clientdb->query("SELECT * FROM cities ORDER BY DATE LIMIT 6");

while($info=$getprops->fetch_assoc()){
    //$results[]=$info['city'];
    echo $info['city']."<br>";
}

?>
```

I m able to get the results in the div below with id resdiv. But the problem is, how do I ensure the value of Var X in the JavaScript function is appended to the load parameter results.php?cit= ?

I get 'x.value' being passed rather than the actual value of x. I think once I do that, eventually I can match the variable to the results array and show matching auto-complete kind of results.

Comment: You have enclosed document ready inside your function. That's not right.

Comment: Ok @mohit, thanks for the info. WIl remove that. Though it still works that way.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj really?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I thought so :) Doesn't it only bind the enclosed function to the event when document is ready, and because the document is most probably already ready, the code inside this handler should not get called again?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj it's ugly code for sure. But yes, at call, DOM *will* be ready and there's nothing wrong :)

Comment: @mohit YES ! You are a life saver ! Thanks a ton. That did it. I guess now I probably can have a rough autocomplete script patched up :) Will accept your answer in 6 mins as the messages says when I try to accept the answer

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Ok, so document ready is like a condition. Actually I think of it as an event handler so I thought running it after document ready has fired would cause it to never fire again. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Actually my issue was the + and ' positioning in the parameter. The document ready function never really created trouble for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `x.value` outside your quotes as that's a variable. You can make your code much shorter than it currently is. You should not have any issues with following way:

```
$("#cit").on("keyup", function(){
    var x = document.getElementById("cit").value;
    $('#resdiv').load('results.php?cit='+x.value);
});//

<input type="" name="" id="cit">
<div id='resdiv'></div>
```

Comment: but you post is nicer, though =) +1 to you.

Answer (score 2):

regarding to your code, you have an error here:

```
$('#resdiv').load('results.php?cit=x.value');
```

change this to:

```
$('#resdiv').load('results.php?cit=' + x.value);
```